# iframe with Youtube video appears for logged-in users, but not for incognito users

Tags: admin, embed, youtube

I have a YouTube video on a site's homepage, but when viewing the site as an unknown / non-logged-in user, it's **NOT** showing up at all.

And when viewing in admin / a logged-in WP user of the site, it **DOES** show up.

What could be causing this? Other than using some 3rd party theme / plugins, is there any built-in Wordpress functionality that could be causing this issue?

Here's how I'm embedding the video on the page:

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/8D0pwUeody4"
    width="240"
    height="135" 
    frameborder="0"
    allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen">
</iframe>
```

And here's the site in question:
http://www.canadiancooperator.coop/en/

I'll continue to look in the theme's / plugins' settings just to be sure I haven't overlooked anything, but if this is a known issue please let me know.

### EDIT:

Things I've checked:

- Tested on different browsers (Chrome [+ incognito], Internet Explorer).
- Disabled AdBlock on domain / altogether.
- Tried the `[embed ...]youtube.com/...[/embed]` approach - didn't show on both.

Regarding the Theme and Plugins used that may have something to do with this:

- Theme is: Vantage (Premium) by SiteOrigin (Version: 2.4.4).
- Plugin: Page Builder by SiteOrigin (Homepage uses a **SiteOrigin Editor** with the above `<iframe>` code).

Edit 2: It could very well be something to do with the SiteOrigin theme / plugin, I've tested a new posts in plain HTML (instead of using the Page Builder tool) and sure enough it displays the iframe/youtube video in incognito tabs fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently only using the youtube URL in the SiteOrigin Editor is enough:

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/8D0pwUeody4
```

https://siteorigin.com/thread/youtube-video-not-displaying-on-smartphone/#comment-86750

That being said, this means you can't configure anything on the youtube container (width, height, allowing fullscreen, etc.)

Comment: That is enough because [WordPress auto-embed feature](https://codex.wordpress.org/Embeds), no because SiteOrigen plugin.

Comment: Don't forget to accept your answer and close the question.

Comment: In 2 days (gotta wait).